# Change D5 Fonts - win8 looks bad

Tags: delphi, fonts, default, delphi-5

Is there a way to change the default Font for all of the Components on a Form?

In win8, the default "MS Sans Serif" looks thin and washed out. There is a new Font shown just above it in the list and I assume MSoft added it for win8 for some reason. It is called "Microsoft Sans Serif" and is a much cleaner and lightly Bold-ed Font.

[I used this link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26668) to change the default for Forms, thinking (hoping) that all components would use the Parent-Font, but sadly, no. The only thing that Registry tweak changed was the Title Font for the Form. The body of the Form and thus the components on it are still using the skinny old "MS Sans Serif."

Is there some way to force all components to use the newer Font, other than changing the Form's body-Font every time?

Comment: For Windows 8? Nah. Microsoft Sans Serif, the TrueType font, was added in Windows 2000, and actually *isn't* distributed with Windows 8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10588660/62576

Comment: Follow Ken's link and read my answer there. In summary, set Application.DefaultFont.

Comment: DefaultFont is not available in Delphi 5, which he indicates he is using in his Subject line.

Comment: Are you sure the registry setting didn't work? Create a new form and see what font it uses. Perhaps the setting only applies to new forms, which haven't had their fonts set already. For old forms, can't you just set the `Font` property? It should automatically apply to all the other controls, too, except for the ones where `ParentFont` is false.

Comment: @RobKennedy The registry setting is only for creating new forms in the IDE.

Comment: @RobKennedy Umm, try not to be too superior Rob, then how did it get into the list of Fonts in a two-day old copy of win8 on a new laptop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks David, but 'Application.DefaultFont' declares an "Undeclared Identifier," error in D5. I assume I add that in the first Form OnCreate event? Is there anywhere I can change the Font in the Form .pas file and rebuild? This is the D5-Ent version with source.

Comment: As others have said, your very old delphi doesn't have DefaultFont. What you should do is make all your forms have a common ancestor. And set the font there.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't read Wikipedia carefully enough before I posted. Microsoft Sans Serif is included with Windows 8, but it's a different version of the font than what came with Windows 2000. Regardless, it's not a *new* font. Windows 2000 used Tahoma, and I think it was Vista that introduce Segoe UI. Consider using one of those instead. Or check out [MS Shell Dlg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374112.aspx).

Comment: @RobKennedy I think that initially Tahoma was only bundled with Office. Somewhere around Windows XP it got bundled with Windows.

Comment: @Jeroen, Wikipedia says it was distributed with Windows 95 and was the default font for Windows 2000.

Comment: @RobKennedy I just checked some of my VMs and some online references. In the pre-Windows 2000 era, Tahoma wasn't part of Windows itself: you needed Office 97+ or the Word 97+ Viewer to get it installed. Some interesting reads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057239/which-font-is-the-default-for-mfc-dialog-controls/6057761#6057761 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163277. The Microsoft Typography site used to have for each font family a list of products that it was shipped in, but that is broken right now: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=19

Comment: Hi sorry @RobKennedy I thought I'd just ask a very similar question here rather than start a new thread. I too have D5 applications and my Sans Serif looks thin and dated on Win7/Win8. I changed to MS Reference Sans Serif which looks bolder and cleaner. However many client PCs don't seem to have this installed as default. What do you guys recommend a best practice future-proofed Font? Thanks

Comment: Post a new question, @Notidaho. Your question is not the same as this one; you're not asking how to change the default font of a form. You're asking for font recommendations, and your question really has nothing to do with Delphi. By asking in a comment, your question will be seen by very few people, and nobody can vote on the answers you get.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 5 has no support for the [DefaultFont](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Forms.TApplication.DefaultFont) property.

You could work around it by setting the `ParentFont` property of all your forms and controls to true.

With or without `DefaultFont`: *all* fonts in your application (especially `Name`, `Height`, and `Style`) would have to be the same to make this work.

An alternative way to approach your problem is by writing a method that recursively visits all controls, and replaces the [Name](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Graphics.TFont.Name) property of `Fonts` on `Forms`/`Controls` into the name of a font that *is* installed. This would work in all Delphi versions.

So the answer is yes you can.

Edit: example of how such a method could look like: [Font consistency throughout Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588660/font-consistency-throughout-project/10590236#10590236)

Comment: I was not aware that 20th century delphi had no DefaultFont. Without that the way forward is to derive all forms from a common base.