# How to use Windows default font in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts, delphi-xe5

As you know, the default font in `Windows XP` and `Windows 7` is `Tahoma`. But in `Windows 8` and `8.1`, it changed to `Segoe UI`.

Even though my application is running on Windows 8.1, the default font in it, is `Tahoma`.

So my question is how can I recognize default windows font with delphi? So my `labels`, `textboxes` ,etc... will show in Tahoma font when my app is running under windows XP and they'll show in `Segoe UI` font when my app is running under `windows 8`.

[image]

By the way I tried to change the font to `default` but it didn't help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588660/font-consistency-throughout-project

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I have no problem with changing a font. I just want to find the default windows font using Delphi.

Comment: If you read David's answer there, you can deduce that you can modify Application.DefaultFont with one of Screen.XXFont properties and then through the use of ParentFont property you can have what you want. More or less.. You probably want to have a look at Screen.IconFont etc..

Comment: There is no single default font. Which one do you want?

Comment: Isn't the 'standard' GUI font `Segoe UI` already in Vista?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The font is used in Winddows explorer.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes but I didn't mention it :)

Comment: Which font? I would not be surprised if explorer used more than one. It has menus and window captions and tree and list views and button text. Do they all use the same font?

Comment: Thanks to @DavidHeffernan my problem solved with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10590062/2570054.

Comment: @Sky - That link is the same question I posted in the first comment.